# Password protected page, how to access it with PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel

Say I have a page which is password protected with cPanel's directory password type of thing (htaccess), how could I access this page using PHP? So the php script would:

1. Go to the password protected URL
2. Enter the username
3. Enter the password
4. Return true if it worked, false if it didnt

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

You can set the connection options for `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH` and pass the credentials. There's actually a [user comment containing code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#98164) that should help you get started with Basic Auth.